# Поиск значения "выбивающегося" из массива значений

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Есть массив чисел, по значению приблизительно одинаковые. Среди них есть несколько чисел которые отличаются в разы. *Подскажите алгоритм как найти эти значения?*

Вот графический пример. Таких всплесков может быть несколько и различной амплитуды.
[image: Графический пример. Подобная иллюстрация.]

Comment: Что-то типа правила трех сигма? Посчитать среднеквадратичное отклонение от среднего, и все, выпадающее за определенную полосу, убирать?

Answer (score 2):

Как я это вижу, или мне неведомы цели и кажется все элементарно:

1) Искать средние значения двух равных промежутков времени (либо трех промежутков, для уменьшения вероятности ситуации, когда всплески идут один за другим)
2) Сравнивать полученные значения и брать меньшее
3) Установить правило отличия всплеска, пример: если амплитуда больше в три и более раз (здесь все-таки надо проработать значение превышения), чем найденное меньшее среднее - это всплеск.

По графику, как это будет работать (значения на глаз): беру временные промежутки 100..200 и 200..300. В первом промежутке среднее значение 0,1 (беру только значащие цифры, т.е. до запятой), на втором промежутке попадает всплеск и среднее значение увеличивается примерно до 0,25. Берем значение 0,1 и сравниваем с амплитудами по установленному правилу.

Если сумел помочь, то буду рад